# How to prove that $53^{103}+ 103^{53}$ is divisible by 39?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is a problem in my number theory textbook. It is based on modular arithmetic but im not getting how to start off to prove this. Please give me some hints on how to solve it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As $39=13\cdot3$

For non-negative integers $m,n$

$\displaystyle53\equiv1\pmod{13}\implies53^n\equiv1$ and $\displaystyle103\equiv-1\pmod{13}\implies103^{53}\equiv(-1)^{53}$

$\displaystyle\implies53^{103}+103^{53}\equiv1+(-1)\pmod{13}$

and $\displaystyle53\equiv-1\pmod3\implies53^{103}\equiv(-1)^{103}$ and $\displaystyle103\equiv1\pmod3\implies103^m\equiv1$

$\displaystyle\implies53^{103}+103^{53}\equiv-1+(1)\pmod3$

Comment: @Downvoter, Please have a look into the edited version

Comment: Probably the downvote is because you posted two separate answers. I too [got downvoted](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/908639/242) recently, presumably for that (even though my answers were $3$ years apart, and conceptually different).

Comment: @BillDubuque, The downvote came much before the other answer

Comment: Indeed, checking the times shows that the downvote was placed $67$ seconds after you posted the answer - not even enough time to carefully read the answer.

Comment: You might get downvotes when your answer is rewarding someone who has shown no work.

Answer (score 6):

$$53\equiv14\pmod{39},103\equiv-14\pmod{53}$$

$$53^{103}+103^{53}\equiv14^{103}+(-14)^{53}\pmod{39}\equiv14^{53}[(14)^{50}-1]$$

Now $\displaystyle14^1\equiv1\pmod{13},14^1\equiv-1\pmod3\implies14^2\equiv(-1)^2\equiv1$

$\displaystyle\implies14^{\text{lcm}(1,2)}\equiv1\pmod{3\cdot13}$

or directly by observation, $\displaystyle14^2=196\equiv1\pmod{195}\equiv1\pmod{39}$

$\implies14^{2n}\equiv1$ for non-negative integer $n$

---

**Generalization** :

We need $\displaystyle a\equiv1\pmod3,\equiv-1\pmod {13}$ and $\displaystyle b\equiv-1\pmod3,\equiv1\pmod {13}$ where $a,b$ are odd integers

So, $\displaystyle a=3A+1=13B-1$ for some integers $A,B$

$\iff\displaystyle3A=13B-2=13B-(2\cdot13-3\cdot8)\iff3(A-8)=13(B-2)$

$\displaystyle\implies\frac{3(A-8)}{13}=B-2$ which is an integer

$\displaystyle\implies13|3(A-8)\iff13|(A-8)$ as $(13,3)=1$

$\displaystyle\implies A=8+13C\implies a=3(8+13C)+1=39(C+1)-14\equiv-14\pmod{39}$

Similarly, we can derive $\displaystyle b\equiv14\pmod{39}$

But one condition, $a,b$ must be odd integers

We can further generalize this any two relative prime  odd integers

Answer (score 2):

${\rm mod}\ \ \ 3\!:\ n = 53^{\large j}\! + 103^{\large k}\equiv (\color{#0a0}{-1})^{\large j}\ \ +\,\ \ \color{#c00}1^{\large k} \equiv\, \color{#0a0}{-1}\color{#c00}{+1}\equiv 0,\ $ assuming $\,j\,$ is odd.

${\rm mod}\ 13\!:\ n = 53^{\large j}\! + 103^{\large k}\equiv \ \ \ \  \color{#c00}1^{\large j}\, +\,(\color{#0a0}{-1})^{\large k} \equiv\, \color{#c00}{{+}1}\color{#0a0}{-1}\equiv 0,\ $ assuming $\,k\,$ is odd.

So $\ 3,13\mid n\,\Rightarrow\, 39\mid n\  $ by $\ {\rm lcm}(3,13) = 3\cdot 13\ $ (or by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242)) $\ $  **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ The above innate $\rm\color{#c00}{sym}\color{#0a0}{metry}$ above can be brought to the fore as in [this answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/843751/242) i.e.

$$\{a,b\} \equiv \{\color{#c00}{+c},\,\color{#0a0}{-c}\,\}\,\ {\rm  mod}\,\ m\,\&\,n\ \Rightarrow\ {\rm lcm}(m,n)\mid a\!+\!b\qquad\qquad$$

The congruence arithmetic above employs the basic [Congruence Sum and Power Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)