# Calculate the rest of the division of $(4^{103} + 2(5^{104}))^{102}$ by $13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I already know some techniques to solve big exponents such as, Euler/Fermat Theorem,Euler/Carmichael,successive squaring.

But these problems seem to be more dificult as they involve operations insted of a single number.

How could I solve them ?

- $(4^{103} + 2(5^{104}))^{102}$ by $13$
- $53^{103}+103^{53}$ by $39$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909973/how-to-prove-that-53103-10353-is-divisible-by-39

Comment: Are you only interested in the remainder.  Or do you want to know the quotient as well?

Comment: Operations don't make things worse.  If $4^{103} \equiv a \mod 13$ then $(4^103 + 2(5^{104}))^{102} \equiv (a + 2(5^{104}))^{102} \mod 13$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 
(4^{103}+2 \cdot 5^{104})^{102}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
(4^{3 \cdot 34+1}+2 \cdot 5^{2 \cdot 52})^{102}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
(4^{3 \cdot 34}4^1+2 \cdot 5^{2 \cdot 52})^{102}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
\\ 
\left((4^{3})^{34} \cdot 4^1+2 \cdot (5^{2})^{52}\right)^{102}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
\left(64^{34} \cdot 4^1+2 \cdot 25^{52}\right)^{102}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
\\ 
\left((-1)^{34}4^1+2(-1)^{52}\right)^{102}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
6^{102}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
6^{6}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
36^{3}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
10^{3}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
100.10\overset{13}{\equiv} 
9.10\overset{13}{\equiv} 
-1 
$$

---

---

$$ 
53^{103}+103^{53}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
1^{103}+(-1)^{53}\overset{13}{\equiv} 
1-1\overset{13}{\equiv} 0;
$$

$$ 
53^{103}+103^{53}\overset{3}{\equiv} 
(-1)^{103}+1^{53}\overset{3}{\equiv} 
-1+1\overset{3}{\equiv} 0;
$$

which implies that $53^{103}+103^{53}\overset{39}{\equiv} 0$ .

Comment: why did you compute the $53^{103}+103^{53}≡0 \mod 39$?

Comment: @shabnamjamali ; My dear shabnamjamali, because it was asked -as the second part of question- in the first version of question, before edites makes changes.

Comment: @Famke someone asked for me to leave only one question in the comments, I'll add it again

Comment: @hjx , I am ok with both of them, but I think there is no need to remove one of them.

Comment: @Ok, Could you please explain a bit more the second one, The first one is a question to leave in blank in the exam, I'll focus on the second, I Have been studying this subject for only 2 weeks.

Comment: @hjx ; Only notice that $53\overset{13}{\equiv} 1$ and $103\overset{13}{\equiv} -1$; also notice that $53\overset{3}{\equiv} -1$ and $103\overset{3}{\equiv} 1$. Did it help you?

Comment: $λ(39) = 12$, so $53^{12} \equiv 1$ mod $39$, I got used to solving the questions this way, but $39 = 13 * 3$, I don't know what you thought to use the factorization of 39 to solve this, But as it is not an easy subject, I'll spend a time thinking to understand.

Comment: Anything I'll talk to you later, Thanks for the interest in helping me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @hjx ; Only notice that for every prime numbers $p \neq q$ ; we have $pq \mid A$ if and only if  $p \mid A$ and  $q \mid A$. In other words $A\overset{pq}{\equiv}0$ if and only if  $A\overset{p}{\equiv}0$ and $A\overset{q}{\equiv}0$.

Comment: @hkx Remark that the above innate $\rm\color{#c00}{sym}\,\color{#0a0}{metry}$ can be brought to the fore as follows 

$$\begin{align} \{a,\ b\} &\equiv \{\color{#c00}{+c},\,\color{#0a0}{-c}\,\}\,\ {\rm  mod}\,\ m,\,n\ \Rightarrow\ {\rm lcm}(m,n)\mid a\!+\!b\\[.4em]
{\rm so}\ \  \{53^{103},103^{53}\} &\equiv \{\color{#c00}{+1},\,\color{#0a0}{-1}\,\}\,\ {\rm  mod}\: 13,\,3\ \Rightarrow\ {\rm lcm}(13,3)\mid 53^{103}\!+\!13^{53}\\[.4em]
{\rm because}\ \{53,\,103\} &\equiv \{\color{#c00}{+1},\,\color{#0a0}{-1}\,\}\,\ {\rm  mod}\: 13,\,3\ \ {\rm and}\ \ 103,53\ \ {\rm are\ odd}
\end{align}$$

Comment: That explains the genesis of the divisiility. This symmetric viewpoint is explained further in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/843751/242), including the easy proof. See also the links there for generalizations.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks, let's check If I got it, 39 can be written as a product of 2 numbers, if the lcm of these 2 numbers can divide a + b, this implies that the {a,b}  mod m,n are congruent to the same numbers with the difference that the signs are different.

Comment: @BillDubuque How did you notice that property ? by checking or by looking ?

Comment: @hjx It seems you have the implication reversed. See the linked answer for more details. The generalization is not difficult to see after introspecting on special cases.

Comment: @BillDubuque I've never heard of this property do You have any book reference ?

Comment: @hjx I've never seen it mentioned anyhwere else.

Answer (score 1):

*Variants* :

*First congruence* :

Observe first that $2$ has order $12 \bmod13$, so $4$ has order $6$, and that as $5^2\equiv -1\mod 13$, $5$ has order $4$. Thus 
$$4^{103}+2\cdot 5^{104}\equiv 4^{103\bmod 6}2\cdot 5^{104\bmod 4}=4^1+2\cdot 5^0=6.$$
Now $6=2\cdot 3$ and we know $2$ has order $12 \bmod 13$, whereas $3$ has order $3$. We conclude that
$$6^{102}\equiv 2^{102\bmod 12}\cdot3^{102\bmod 3}=2^6\cdot3^0\equiv -1\mod 13.$$

*Second congruence* :

Using the *Chinese remainder theorem*, it is enough to calculate the expression modulo $3$ and modulo $13$.

- Modulo $3$: $\;53\equiv 2$, which has order $2\bmod 3$, and $103\equiv 1$, so
  $$53^{103}+103^{53}\equiv 2^{103\bmod 2}+1^{53}\equiv 0\mod 3.$$
- Modulo $13$: $\;53\equiv 1$ and $103\equiv -1$, so $$53^{103}+103^{53}\equiv 1+(-1)^{53}\equiv 0\mod 13.$$

The *Chinese remainder theorem* asserts the canonical map
$$\mathbf Z/39\mathbf Z\longrightarrow\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/13\mathbf Z $$
is an isomorphism, so we conclude that $\;53^{103}+103^{53}\equiv 0\mod 39$.